# Difference in years between start date and system time

Tags: sql, database

I have the dates of when employees have begun working at a zoo, however i need to figure out how long they have been working there for. I have done my research and know what i need to do, but i cant seem to figure out the syntax for incorporating the NOW() function within the DATEDIFF function. I have to display all active employees and the amount of years (with 2 decimal places) they have been working for.

I have two columns, Joined (Date) and Resigned (date, where may equal null if employee is active)

So lets just say that someone started working on 1996-09-18 (yyyy/mm/dd).

please help, thank you kindly.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Welcome to S/O. In general, it's a good idea to supply things you've tried - you'll learn more if you give it a good go first `:)`

Comment: (Please retag your question with your database type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming you are using MySQL - from the `NOW()` function)

I think you need to use `COALESCE()` function so either `Resigned` or `NOW()` is used in the calculation by `DATEDIFF()`:

```
DATEDIFF(COALESCE(Resigned, CURDATE()), Joined)  AS days
```

So, you could have something like:

```
(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(Resigned, CURDATE()), Joined)) / 365   AS years
```

or:

```
(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(Resigned, CURDATE()), Joined)) / 365.25   AS years
```

If you want to be extremely accurate about extreme cases and leap years, a more complex calculation will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Years with 2 decimal places (Assuming TSQL)

```
SELECT ROUND( 
         CONVERT(FLOAT,
            DATEDIFF(day,joined,ISNULL(resigned,GETDATE()) ))/365,2)
```